# Failed to download packages while updating 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, updates

I am working on 12.04 and while I am trying to install the updates, some of them were downloaded but others failed by displaying a message that said:

```
Failed to downloaded packages & check your Internet connection.
```

Also when I tried to change the server to main, the following  details are given to me:

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_14.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-gnome-support_14.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a sign that you need to update your package list (`sudo apt-get update`). Repos clean out their old packages so if you don't update before doing things, you'll end up trying to download old packages.

In this instance, Thunderbird is now version 15.